# Mysql - Как объединить две таблицы из двух баз в одну?

Tags: mysql

как я могу объединить две одинаковые таблицы из двух баз в одну, учитывая что в обоих таблицах может быть один и тот же игрок и создавать нового не надо, а просто сложить сумму денег из двух юзеров и записать,  если же игрок только в одной таблице, просто записать.

```sql
CREATE TABLE `shopnp_players` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `auth` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
  `money` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `lastconnect` int(11) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE `shop_players` (
  `id` int(5) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(32) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'unknown',
  `auth` varchar(22) NOT NULL,
  `money` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `lastconnect` int(10) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Поля name, lastconnect не обязательны.

Возможно ли сделать это через Mysql или приходить к какому-нибудь яп? Если возможно, то как?

Comment: `select ..., sum(momey) from (select ... from t1 union all select ... ftom t2) x group by ...`

Comment: @Mike , две разные бд.

Comment: Если БД на одном сервере, то просто пишите имена таблиц как `db_name1.table`. А если на разных - настроить получение данных с удаленного сервера через federated engine. Если и это не выходит - тогда только внешним скриптом

Comment: @Mike А можешь пожалуйста поподробнее расписать, немного не понятно =с.